# React remove minor errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

When i give **npm start** while compiling the application to run and see changes i am always getting Minor Errors like: -

1. Remove **<...ComponentName />** with ComponentName/>  and others like these just to remove **spaces all around**, help me on this to reduce time taken for compiling app. {Error only to remove spaces everywhere}
2. npm: Cannot find **module** moment. I checked its present under node_modules, some times it comes while compiling and sometimes it doesn't, no sense why is this happening!

Application using ReactJs and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

it should be like that...

```
<ComponentName> </Component>
```

or

```
<ComponentName />
```

Comment: yes i am doing that.. ex:- 
<Component
name={this.props.name}
/>
But this error is not confined to here i just gave an example what error i am facing!